# Python Wand error when trying to display simple empty image: 'no encode delegate for this image format'

Tags: python-3.x, wand

I'm new to Wand, I tried the following very simple code, to display a red image:

```
from wand.color import Color
import wand.display

with Image(width=100, height=100, background=Color("red")) as img: 
    wand.display.display(img)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
MissingDelegateError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6badc0244551> in <module>
    1 with Image(width=100, height=100, background=Color("red")) as img:
----> 2     wand.display.display(img)
    3 

~/dev/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wand/display.py in display(image, server_name)
    60         ext = '.' + image.format.lower()
    61         path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=ext)
---> 62         image.save(filename=path)
    63         os.system(('start ' if system == 'Windows' else 'open ') + path)
    64     else:

~/dev/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wand/image.py in save(self, file, filename, adjoin)
8916                 r = library.MagickWriteImage(self.wand, filename)
8917             if not r:
-> 8918                 self.raise_exception()
8919 
8920 

~/dev/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py in raise_exception(self, stacklevel)
    228             warnings.warn(e, stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
    229         elif isinstance(e, Exception):
--> 230             raise e
    231 
    232     def make_blob(self, format=None):

MissingDelegateError: no encode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1240
```

Looking at the stack trace, I realize Wand temporarily stores the image in a file before displaying it, so I tried adding the following line before calling `display()`:

```
img.format = 'png'
```

And it works. Am I missing something here? Is this the expected way of displaying a simple image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something here? Is this the expected way of displaying a simple image?

The solution you came up with is correct. For Windows / macOS, [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) assumes you are not running an X11 server. It's far easier to write the Image to disk, and ask the OS to display it in your default image viewer.

### The problem

When creating a canvas, or a pseudo image format (`PLASMA:` for example), the internal "image info" & coder have yet to be defined. Is your simple image CMYK, or RGB? What about palettes, endianness, & etc etc. ImageMagick is right to throw an exception until the user specifies, at a minimum, a coder / delegate to write with.

### The fix

Luckily, with most open-source projects, this was reported and patched in Wand a month ago(?). Wand's `display()` method will hand over a PNG file to the OS in the event that a Image's coder (format) is not defined.

Unluckily, with most open-source projects, it can take weeks for patch versions to be shipped & distributed. Best keep an eye on [Wand's release notes](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/changes.html#version-0-6-2)